# Inserir JavaScript no TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

Gostaria de saber se é possível configurar o TinyMCE para aceitar trechos de código JavaScript campo de digitação, e caso seja possível, qual é a configuração necessária para ativar essa opção.

Answer (score 1):

Basta apenas utilizar a opção de habilitar código fonte, basta clicar em tools, source code.
Neste local você poderá colar embed de outros sites.